# How to change the input menu input method order

Tags: keyboard, input-source, ios

I use 3 input methods.

[image]

The order of input methods on here is what I want, in this order: English, Chinese(Wubi), Japanese(Hiragana) but when comes to the input menu of status bar:

[image]

I want to change it's order to: U.S., Wubi, Hiragana. I searched around but couldn't find any way. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried removing both and then adding them again in the order that you want?

Comment: @TomGewecke Yes, and still the same.